# How to use 就像 when the subjects of the two clauses are different?

Tags: translation, grammar

I'm wanting to say "I'm going to support you as though you were my friend" or "I'm going to support you like a friend", something to that effect. There's probably a more colloquial way of translating this, but specifically I'm trying to use 就像 in this way to learn the grammar. Are any of these following sentences grammatically correct?

(1) 我要支持你，就像你是我的朋友（一样）

(2) 我要就像你是我的朋友（一样）支持你

(3) 就像你是我的朋友，我要支持你

Also, the 一样 is optional, correct?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not sure if 就像 is the best grammar for this type of sentence, I've always seen it used for more literal resemblences.  To me using it in your sentence structure would imply a physical/behavioral similarity to an existing friend, not the metaphorical similarity intended (although I am not native so maybe there is a use I don't know). I would recommend a different practice sentence for learning to avoid confusion (and maybe 似乎 or 仿佛 would be better for the current sentence requested?)

Comment: IMO, 我会 is a better fit than 我要 here.

Answer (score 1):

All  incorrect. clause types are mismatched

(1) 我要[**支持**]你，就像[**你是我的朋友**一样]

(2) 我要就像[**你是我的朋友**]一样[**支持**]你

(3) 就像[**你是我的朋友一样**]，我要[**支持**]你

> 我要就像[**支持**]朋友一样[**支持**]你

Comment: Interesting, appreciate your help.

Comment: Of course, it implies "they are not real friends"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure in what context you would say that, but you can put it like this:

I will support you in this matter as I would support a good friend.
在这件事上我会像支持好朋友一样支持你。

Answer (score 0):

These are my two sentences.

我**會**支持你，**就像**你支持我 - I'll support you as you supported me.

With a little twist, you can say:

我**要**支持你，**就像**你曾經支持過我 - I want to support you the way you have ever supported me (before).

You can also say:

**就像**你支持我一样, 我**會/要**支持你 - The same as you have supported me, I will/want to support you.

It is maybe a little confusing, but the basic form is "I will do something **as** you did **the same** to me", or "**The same as** you did to me, I'll do it in return."